# Set picture as background in python in turtle module

Tags: python, module, turtle-graphics

I am a beginner at programming at can't seem to figure out how to use `bgpic('photo.gif')` in [turtle](http://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html).

I have enclosed the 'photo.gif' in the same folder as the script. Every time I execute the program with bgpic, the turtle window crashes. Do I have to resize the picture? Change its format?

Comment: Can you run the script from console and add the error output to your question?

Comment: TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "naturee.gif"

Comment: Seems like the image is not in GIF format. Are you on Windows or Linux? If on Linux, you can try `file naturee.gif` to check the file type. On Windows, you can use the Explorer to check for file meta information (like width and height).

Comment: I'm using mac OS X, I just edited the extension of the picture by adding '.gif'. Is that not sufficient? If gif the only format python recognises?

Comment: @MaxI. Consider what you just did, and why that might cause an error. Try using the correct file extension.

Comment: @Max: Hah? No, but how *is* the file encoded? Can you check by calling `file naturee.gif` from console? The problem seems to be that Tcl can't decode the file, so it must be in some strange format (the file extension should not matter, @Marcin)

Comment: then, what the actual format of your image is ? Forget about the possibility of changing format by modifying the filename extensions...

Comment: Ok, I used a picture format converter to properly reencode the picture format which solved the problem. Thank a lot for you help Niklas.

Comment: @Max: That's nice. If this solved your problem, you are encouraged to upvote and accept joaquin's answer.

Answer (score 2):

[bgpic only accepts gif images](http://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html#turtle.bgpic).

You should convert your image to gif format with photoshop or another similar tool or alternatively use for example python PIL to make the conversion programmatically